# How to compile set of java files in different packages and then build .jar file using command line?

Tags: java, command-line, jar, cmd, compilation

I have set of .java files in different packages. For example,

`src
  |- Main.java
  |- pkg1
      |- pkg2
          |- A.java
          |- B.java
          |- C.java
  |- pkg3
      |- pkg4
          |- D.java
          |- E.java`

How can I compile all these .java files and then build the .jar library using command line in Windows platform ?

Comment: Read the documentation of [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) (the compiler), and [jar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html) (the archiver), and you'll eventually need [java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) (to run the code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really use an IDE, its much easier and more productive. It can be done:

```
javac Main.java pkg1\pkg2\A.java pkg1\pkg2\B.java pkg1\pkg2\C.java pkg3\pkg4\D.java pkg3\pkg4\E.java
jar -cf my.jar  *.class pkg1 pkg3
```

That will not have a manifest so it won't be executable.

To make it executable, you need to pick a Main class and create a file named manifest.txt with a text editor:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Main
```

and make the jar with this:

```
 jar -cmf manifest.txt my.jar  *.class pkg1 pkg3
```

Comment: I can't use and ide for this. I have to do it manually. I have to grab the files in the directory and compile and then build the jar through a scheduled process..

Comment: I've found much easier way to compile using a batch file with the command, `for /r %%a in (*.java) do ( javac "%%a" )`. Created the .jar file using your command. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [Apache ANT](http://ant.apache.org/). See their [tutorial](https://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html) to get started.